# How to fix react/no-unknown-property error?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have a react application that I use svg as a logo and deploy in vercel. But I am getting the following errors. I don't get this error in my local, but I get it during deploy. Also, if I change the `featurekey` in my locale, that is, if I make it camelcase, I also get the error in my local. I didn't understand exactly what this is.

```
src/components/Logo/index.js
  Line 16:6:  Unknown property 'featurekey' found   react/no-unknown-property
  Line 29:8:  Unknown property 'xmlnsi' found       react/no-unknown-property
  Line 30:8:  Unknown property 'iextraneous' found  react/no-unknown-property
  Line 41:6:  Unknown property 'featurekey' found   react/no-unknown-property
```

I tried using `camelcase` like `featureKey` but it didn't work, this time it threw the same error for `featureKey`. I also tried to add `.eslintrc.json` this:

```
"react/no-unknown-property": ["error", { ignore: ["jsx"] }],
```

but didn't work.

Logo.js

```
export function Logo(props) {
    return (
        <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            version="1.1"
            width="3162.1000925144112"
            height="970.434162445735"
            viewBox="0 0 3162.1000925144112 970.434162445735"
            {...props}
        >
            <g transform="scale(8.105004625720571) translate(10, 10)">
                <defs id="SvgjsDefs8550"></defs>
                <g
                    id="SvgjsG8551"
                    featurekey="7KWit6-0"
                    transform="matrix(0.9144333410065809,0,0,0.9144333410065809,-2.2989350715586716,14.598966612953934)"
                    fill={props.color ? props.color : '#4F46E5'}
                >
                    <switch xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <foreignObject
                            requiredExtensions="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/"
                            x="0"
                            y="0"
                            width="1"
                            height="1"
                        ></foreignObject>
                        <g
                            xmlnsi="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/"
                            iextraneous="self"
                        >
                            <g>
                                <path d="M48.6,49.7V15c0-2.6-2.1-4.8-4.8-4.8c-11.8,0-23,5-30.9,13.8C5.2,32.8,1.4,44.6,2.8,56.4c2.2,19.4,17.9,34.8,37.4,36.5     c1.2,0.1,2.5,0.2,3.7,0.2c11,0,21.5-4.3,29.3-12.1c1.9-1.9,1.9-4.9,0-6.7L48.6,49.7z M41,83.4C26.2,82.1,13.8,70,12.2,55.3     c-1-9.2,1.8-18.1,7.9-24.9c5-5.6,11.7-9.2,19-10.3v31.1c0,1.6,0.6,3,1.7,4.1l22,22C56.6,81.9,48.8,84.1,41,83.4z"></path>
                                <path d="M60.3,7c-0.9,0-1.8,0.3-2.4,0.9c-0.7,0.6-1,1.5-1,2.4v34.8c0,0.8,0.3,1.6,0.9,2.2l24.6,24.6c0.6,0.6,1.5,1,2.4,1     c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.9,0,1.7-0.4,2.3-1c6.7-7.1,10.3-16.5,10.3-26.3C97.5,24.7,81.2,7.7,60.3,7z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </switch>
                </g>
                <g
                    id="SvgjsG8552"
                    featurekey="ewgXDI-0"
                    transform="matrix(3.3958030320267483,0,0,3.3958030320267483,104.87762310498329,13.019631150989738)"
                    fill={props.color ? props.color : '#4F46E5'}
                >
                    <path d="M4.9902 20.19531 c-2.2559 0 -4.0039 -0.88867 -4.3652 -2.793 l2.3535 -0.66406 c0.30273 1.0742 1.0645 1.4941 2.0117 1.4941 c0.69336 0 1.4453 -0.21484 1.4258 -1.0059 c-0.0097656 -1.0449 -1.5918 -1.1328 -3.1836 -1.6992 c-1.2012 -0.41992 -2.3535 -1.0645 -2.3535 -2.7539 c0 -2.0605 1.709 -3.0078 3.9355 -3.0078 c1.9531 0 3.584 0.74219 3.9746 2.6563 l-2.1777 0.48828 c-0.30273 -0.9375 -0.9668 -1.2695 -1.7871 -1.2695 c-0.74219 0 -1.377 0.26367 -1.377 0.88867 c0 0.79102 1.1621 0.94727 2.4219 1.2891 c1.5527 0.41992 3.252 1.0938 3.252 3.2422 c0 2.3047 -1.9629 3.1348 -4.1309 3.1348 z M15.8203 20.19531 c-3.1934 0 -5.498 -1.9434 -5.498 -5.2246 c0 -3.2617 2.2852 -5.2051 5.498 -5.2051 c3.2324 0 5.5078 1.9434 5.5078 5.2051 c0 3.2813 -2.2852 5.2246 -5.5078 5.2246 z M15.791 17.959 c1.6309 0 2.7441 -1.1914 2.7441 -2.9883 s-1.1133 -2.9883 -2.7441 -2.9883 c-1.5723 0 -2.6758 1.1914 -2.6758 2.9883 s1.1035 2.9883 2.6758 2.9883 z M26.113290625 11.5527 c0.50781 -0.88867 1.8262 -1.709 3.2813 -1.709 l0 2.5098 c-2.1289 0 -3.1445 0.625 -3.1445 2.7539 l0 4.8926 l-2.832 0 l0 -10.039 l2.6953 0 l0 1.5918 z M36.94334375 9.766 c2.6367 0 4.8242 1.9531 4.8242 5.2344 s-2.1875 5.2344 -4.8242 5.2344 c-1.3867 0 -2.5977 -0.55664 -3.1641 -1.543 l-0.068359 1.3086 l-2.666 0 l0 -15 l2.8125 0 l0 6.1816 c0.58594 -0.9082 1.7578 -1.416 3.0859 -1.416 z M36.28904375 17.9004 c1.4941 0 2.666 -1.1035 2.666 -2.9004 c0 -1.8066 -1.1719 -2.9102 -2.666 -2.9102 c-1.4844 0 -2.6563 1.1523 -2.6563 2.9102 s1.1621 2.9004 2.6563 2.9004 z M50.537140625 9.961 l2.8125 0 l0 10.039 l-2.666 0 l-0.068359 -1.2109 c-0.70313 0.88867 -1.8164 1.4063 -3.1934 1.4063 c-2.4121 0 -3.7402 -1.2598 -3.7402 -3.4766 l0 -6.7578 l2.8223 0 l0 6.1523 c0 1.3281 0.83008 1.8164 1.8066 1.8164 c1.1621 0 2.2168 -0.58594 2.2266 -2.4316 l0 -5.5371 z M62.1874875 9.766 c2.4121 0 3.7402 1.25 3.7402 3.4766 l0 6.7578 l-2.8223 0 l0 -6.1523 c0 -1.3379 -0.83008 -1.8262 -1.7969 -1.8262 c-1.1621 0 -2.2168 0.58594 -2.2363 2.4414 l0 5.5371 l-2.8125 0 l0 -10.039 l2.8125 0 l0 1.1133 c0.70313 -0.83008 1.7871 -1.3086 3.1152 -1.3086 z M75.302765625 9.961 l2.8125 0 l0 10.039 l-2.666 0 l-0.068359 -1.2109 c-0.70313 0.88867 -1.8164 1.4063 -3.1934 1.4063 c-2.4121 0 -3.7402 -1.2598 -3.7402 -3.4766 l0 -6.7578 l2.8223 0 l0 6.1523 c0 1.3281 0.83008 1.8164 1.8066 1.8164 c1.1621 0 2.2168 -0.58594 2.2266 -2.4316 l0 -5.5371 z"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    );
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
        "no-console": "error"
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find anything about these attributes so I guess they don't exist. Just remove them